# Seeking Generalisation Strategies for Building Outlines in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geometry, generalization

I have a dataset of building footprints vectorised from a raster dataset.  The dataset is currently just a vector representation of the raster data.  I would like a polygon dataset that only has vertices at the corners of the building.  I have attempted to use the Simplify command in PostGIS with limited success.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are many algorithms dedicated to building simplification. You may have a look at [this website](http://generalisation.icaci.org/index.php/results) for an overview. See also [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/440/162). You could use:

- Building outline simplification: It consist in recursively deleting too short edges of the outline and lengthening the neighbor edges. Example:

[image]

- Smallest surrounding rectangle algorithm: It consist in replacing the building geometry by the smallest surrounding rectangle. This rectangle can also be scaled to the building initial area. Example:

[image]

- Squaring algorithm: It consists in applying a light rotation to edges to make the corners perfectly squared. Example:

[image]

These transformations may be enough for your need. It can be interesting to combine them.

I am almost 100% sure none of these algorithms are implemented in PostGIS. Some are implemented in the [Opencarto](https://github.com/jgaffuri/OpenCarto) java library I am developing. Let me know if you want to test it!

Comment: Can you give a short explanation of what algorithms you refer to in Opencarto for the mentioned "Building outline simplification". I couldn't find direct info in the wiki or code in Opencarto.

Comment: It is "ShortEdgesDeletion". You can find it on github there: https://github.com/jgaffuri/OpenCarto/blob/master/src/main/java/org/opencarto/algo/polygon/ShortEdgesDeletion.java

Comment: Link update: https://github.com/jgaffuri/OpenCarto/blob/gh-pages/src/main/java/org/opencarto/algo/polygon/ShortEdgesDeletion.java

Answer (score 4):

```
geometry ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(geometry geomA, float tolerance);
```

Will avoid creating derived geometries (polygons in particular) that are invalid
http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5SVN/ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology.html

should be a better output than **Simplify**

check your geometry first and after
with `ST_IsSimple(geometry geomA);`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might do the trick:

> "If we buffer by a large amount, then reverse the buffer by the same
>   amount, we’ll get something that has a similar shape to the original,
>   but without the crinkly bits."

http://blog.opengeo.org/2010/11/22/removing-complexities/

Comment: that's an interesting approach and it seems relatively effective. Thanks for the pointer, it's something I'll be able to use. Your answer would be better if it contained a simple phrase containing the core idea being referenced and wasn't just a link.