# Resolve Building Conflicts - the open source way?

Tags: qgis, cartography, simplify

In ArcGIS there is a tool called [*Resolve Building Conflicts*](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/resolve-building-conflicts.htm) and I'd like to achieve the same using only open source tools (QGIS, GDAL etc), preferably on Mac OS instead.

In the long run I'm trying to do exactly what Anna Vetter tries to do in [her thesis](http://129.187.45.33/CartoMasterNew/fileadmin/user_upload/Vetter_Report.pdf) called *The automatic generalisation of buildings whilst maintaining the settlement structure: A case study
based on the 1:50‘000 Swiss National Map Series* but without using ESRI.

I've also seen [this discussion about buildings](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3739/generalisation-strategies-for-building-outlines).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd start with this question: [What are the existing solutions to automate generalisation/simplification of geographical data?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/440/753) -- however, understand that this is not an easy problem to solve, and it's likely that a tool that does exactly what you want does not exist.

Comment: Thanks! The link you provided discuss only methods on simplification. What I'm trying to achieve is the way Resolve Building Conflicts does it, where it moves, scales and simplifies objects. It doesn't have to be one amazing tool. I could definitely use several. Maybe I should edit my question a bit.