# Building footprint polygon simplification / generalisation

Tags: polygon, geometry, software-recommendations, simplify, generalization

I'm looking for implementations of polygon simplification algorithms that preserve topology and overall rectilinearity. The input data is building footprints which often have squarish protrusions and often a predominantly rectilinear shape. A good implementation is Simplify Building in ArcGIS:
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/cartography/simplify-building.htm

However, that version does not preserve topology of adjacent buildings. A topology preserving version was apparently in "Coverage Toolbox" but this appears to rely on the now deprecated ArcInfo Workstation.

Are there any other implementations worth checking out?

FOSS is preferred but not essential.

Note I am not looking for typical polyline simplifications (Douglas-Peuker, Vivasalingham and their variants, there are tons of useful ones in FME) as these are not really applicable to rectilinear building footprints (they weed out vertices and are for more applicable for linear natural or road features)./

[Seeking Generalisation Strategies for Building Outlines in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3739) suggests:

- Geocarto - but that doesn't appear to maintain topology
- ETGeoWizards - can't find a polygon / building simplify there