# Raster display for topographic map

Tags: raster, arcgis-desktop, land-cover

I'm trying to see how good a custom topographic map could be using only free data

For the moment I'm just playing with the data so of course the colours are not pretty.
I did some classification and used some land cover data anyway I have a raster layer as background with the main land cover basically swamp forest and no vegetation.
Since the result of a vectorization was awful and hard to fix I'm going to stay with the raster as background, the question is:

How to avoid the squared shape on my map? I would like to smooth the area to have a prettier map. I tried the bilinear interpolation but it creates white boundaries around the area and with the Nearest neighbour it's not pretty.

I tried some generalization tools as well but they are way too strong!

So what would you do?

Here is what I have done so far:

[image: Progress]

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing your project.  Are you trying to smooth vector or raster data?

Comment: Yes, sorry i couldn't post any picture since i'm new user, i want to smooth a raster file in order to give it smooth delimitation instead of the squared one. http://hpics.li/b6f13ca

Comment: Is it so easy to do that nobody want to answer :D?
Or is the question not accurate?

Comment: no, you just have to specify your search results. There are many people who have the same problem. For example look here for smoothing solutions http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/what-raster-smoothing-generalization-tools-are-available