# Python GDAL: find out spikes and pits in DEM

Tags: python, gdal, analysis, elevation

I'm working with on a DEM (Geotiff) in Python GDAL, and I'd like to find out the spikes or pits in my terrain.
I have no idea how to proceed, does anyone have good algorithm to help me out?

Comment: define 'spikes' and 'pits', and you'll find where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

GDAL doesn't have a ready-made utility for this that I know of.  You would probably have to script something.

However, for filling sinks, GRASS has the [r.fill.dir](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/r.fill.dir.html) and [r.terraflow](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.terraflow.html) functions.  SAGA and some other FOSS raster GIS packages also have sink filling functions too.

Spikes pose a different problem and you'll need to consider a median filter and/or Gausian blur. See [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/what-raster-smoothing-generalization-tools-are-available) for more discussion on spikes.