# How to smooth a raster in a rectangular fashion using gaussian blur?

Tags: raster, generalization

How do I adjust the code for the Gaussian Blur posted in the thread:

[What raster smoothing/generalization tools are available?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/what-raster-smoothing-generalization-tools-are-available)

to retain the resolution/gradients in the y direction and blur only in the x direction (rather than over a square area)?

Comment: My answer there applies directly if you simply use neighborhoods that extend only one cell vertically (that is, in the y direction).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the kernel shape. The linked answer in the question uses a circular kernel shape (not square), since the `size` of x and y values are identical. However, the source code was based on [this cookbook](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/SignalSmooth) which defines a kernel on `size` and optional `sizey`, for a different size in the y-direction. Therefore, the kernel is elliptical, and should do what you are looking for (i.e., a rectangle stretched out in the x-direction).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to make @whuber 's answer directional.

1) take the mean of a 3 pixels by 1 window centered on your pixel. (equivalent to a custom linear neighbourhood with weights of 1/3, 1/3 and 1/3)

2) repeat several times

alternatively, you can define a custom neighborhood with the weights extracted from a Gaussian distribution or other smoothing kernel.