# Creating polyline which is average of multiple other polylines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polyline-creation

I am trying to use ArcGIS for Desktop to create an "average" polyline from several lines. For example if you have multiple hurricane paths and would like to plot the average position of all of the paths. I imagine you could do this if you got the y coordinates for specific x coordinates and worked out the mean of the y coordinates. I am not good at scripting and was wondering of there was a tool that could do this.

Comment: Do you want to do this interactively or by script/program?

Comment: Are the lines always straight or do some have curves/bends etc?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include a real world example of what you are wanting to do, please?  For example, are you trying to collapse road casings to road centrelines, river banks to river centrelines, or something else?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68359/creating-an-average-polygon/104338#104338

Comment: That's a really good post @klewis, however it possibly wont work for polylines unless there's some tricky maths to do with distance rasters that can be applied... I don't know any but would be very interested to see if a raster based approach can centreline two polylines.

Comment: A clearer description is needed. After all, there are infinitely many kinds of averages of just two positive numbers, so guess how many kinds of "averages" of two polylines there might be!  Perhaps you could tell us what this "average position" is intended to represent?

Comment: Question has been updated with a real world example. Hopefully it's a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to draw a feature in between two features then use the [MidPoint](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m70000005p000000) on the editor [Feature Construction](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/The_Feature_Construction_toolbar/01m700000046000000/) toolbar to draw the point exactly in the middle.

If you want to automate this for lots of central features use [Collapse Dual Lines To Centerline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00700000000t000000), some editing afterwards might be required but better than doing it manually for multiple instances.