# Way/tool to create an average of multiple tracks/polylines in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, line, gps

I'm still new at ArcGIS and have about 100 boat tracks taking roughly the same path. For my research, I would like to include the most used path/average of these. I attached a photo of all of my tracks on a map. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: "Most used" and "average of all" are two completely different problems (and average of most used, is yet a third problem which combines the two other problems).  Which of these do you want?  There have been many similar questions for the average of a set of lines.  Eg:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190104/creating-average-polyline-from-set-of-polylines