# Seeking "path averaging" algorithms?

Tags: gps, algorithm

Imagine that I have collected a large set of GPS tracks of objects moving from A to B, and for the sake of simplicity assume they avoid obstacles in a consistent way, so that their path is just "noisy", but not very different.

Are there any algorithms that average those paths to a path that is "representative" of the path all users took?

Comment: Somewhat similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68359/creating-an-average-polygon/68617#68617

Answer (score 1):

though technically not an average, a douglas reduction might work for what you need, getting rid of all the points that are inside a given "cross track" error.

it's a widespread algorithm, so every language or GIS software has an implementation.