# How can I get an average value for area using 30 different vector shapefiles as input?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, overlay, rasterization

I have 30 different vector boundary polygon shapefiles for a study area that don't exactly match up.  Each polygon has a risk score.  I want to overlay all 30 maps into a single map that represents the average risk score of the areas.  I think I need to use vector to raster in ArcMap on the 30 shapefiles, but then I'm not sure how to overlay them.  I've used zonal statistics before, but I'm not sure if that is relevant to this kind of project. I think the final output will have to be a raster since the boundaries of the 30 input files do not match up exactly.

Comment: Similar: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68359/creating-average-polygon/68617#68617

Comment: You can use the [raster calculator](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) to combine them. Just simple raster addition.