# Removing Image Stripes / Scan Line errors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, grass-gis, bathymetry

I have some seabed bathymetry data derived from seismic reflection profiles in a 2.5D dataset (closely spaced lines).

The data was gridded by another worker in SMT Kingdom suite; I'm not familiar with the process, but the result is quite high resolution, but contains scan line errors/striping int he direction of the survey lines.

After some extensive searching via google I'm aware that this can be fixed by using fast fourier transforms (FFT) though I have no idea how to implement this!

I have ArcMap installed on my main desktop machine and would prefer a solution on this, though I do also have GRASS on another machine.

I've attached Images to try and illustrate the problem at hand.

Raw Survey data:

[http://imgur.com/tWNUr5t](https://imgur.com/tWNUr5t)

Inline:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMgG3.jpg

I can't post the crossline image, but it is in the album on imgur

Comment: Check this out: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/9434/8104

Comment: See also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Image_destriping

Answer (score 1):

In **[GRASS GIS](http://grass.osgeo.org/)**, you can use [**r.fillnulls**](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.fillnulls.html):

> ***r.fillnulls*** - Fills no-data areas in raster maps using spline
>   interpolation.

or **[r.neighbors](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.neighbors.html)**, if you want to apply a filter, and then **[r.patch](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.patch.html)** between the input raster and the filtered one, in order to replace NULLs with the filtered values.

> ***r.neighbors*** - Makes each cell category value a function of the
>   category values assigned to the cells around it, and stores new cell
>   values in an output raster map layer.

Comment: would that still work? the errors have values that are above what they are supposed to be, ie they are about 2-5m above the actual seabed