# Shapefile to GeoJSON conversion

Tags: shapefile, geojson, openlayers-2

I am working with `OpenLayers`. I want to convert `Shapefile` into `GeoJSON` format and send it to browser to show with `OpenLayers`. But the problem is that when the size of my Shapefile is bigger than 60Mb, then it is not convenient to send whole `GeoJSON` data to browser.

Anyone can help me, how can i minimize the `GeoJSON` file size while my `Shapefile` size is still very large.

Are there any tools or techniques by which I can encode `GeoJSON` data to minimize the size and send it to client side as well as decode this data to show in map.

Comment: This post could be interesting to read for your need: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/how-to-create-vector-polygons-at-the-same-amazing-speeds-giscloud-is-able-to-ren

Answer (score 6):

As said by neogeomat, [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) format is probably a good alternative, but I think you should first apply the following steps :

1. First of all, you should wander if **geometries stored in shapefile could not be generalized** -regarding to your online needs? You could, for sure, reduce dramatically the size of your file. To apply the cartographic generalization you can use the online tool [mapshaper](http://mapshaper.org/). You can also try [in QGIS](http://www.techques.com/question/26-25914/How-to-smooth-generalize-a-polygon-in-qgis) or other GIS softwares.
2. Then, **delete unused attributes** from the database.
3. Then, you can also gain some weight by **reducing the coordinate precision**. Using ogr2ogr, the command will be similar to

   ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -lco COORDINATE_PRECISION=2 output.json my_input.shp
4. And **finally convert the file to topojson**, with this online tool, for example :  http://jeffpaine.github.io/geojson-topojson/

As references, you can read :

- In english : http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2012/11/how-to-minify-geojson-files.html
- In French [this page](http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/reduire-le-poids-dun-geojson), which explains how to switch from a 44 Mb shapefile to a 98 kb geojson file.

Answer (score 1):

The "canonical" way (and the only feasible way to handle medium to big size data) would be to load the shapefile in a WMS/WFS server (geoserver), and use WMS for the visualization of the data, and WFS (as GeoJSON, but could by gml or whatever) when you need to select a feature or to see the attributes as table. You can give a look at [OpenGeo Suite](http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/opengeo-suite/download/)

Maybe you could try to minimize the coordinates of the shapes using the [Google Maps algorithm](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm), it seems that the encoded form is supported by OL [EncodedPolylineFormat](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/EncodedPolyline-js.html).

Answer (score 0):

TopoJson has smaller file size than corresponding GeoJson. You can send the data as topojson, then convert it to geojson in client or [read topojson](https://gist.github.com/jseppi/4674203) directly  in openlayers