# How to speed up the process of vector data visualization for a web application

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, visualisation, model

I have a GIS web application and vector data that is going from the model to the web application. For developing the User Interface I am using JavaScript and OpenLayers. But sometimes the amount of geospatial data that I need to simultaneously visualize on a map is very big (10 000+ objects) and the browser cannot respond to all user requests. So, how can I speed up the process of visualization **(both model and UI part)** of large amounts of geodata?

Comment: Can you generalize (pre-process) your data for the web?

Answer (score 2):

check out AnimatedCluster strategy for OpenLayers [here](https://github.com/acanimal/AnimatedCluster) for big data and good ui.
you can find code example [here](http://acuriousanimal.com/code/animatedCluster/).

[image: cluster]

beside this examine openlayers clustering example.

- Cluster Strategy Example, [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/strategy-cluster.html)
- Extended clustering, [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/strategy-cluster-extended.html)

  i hope it helps you...

Comment: Is it possible to somehow cache objects in order to speed up visualization process?

Comment: AFAIK, you can cache your image tile OpenLayers.Control.CacheRead and CacheWrite method.

Answer (score 2):

The techniques to solve your issue and improve vector web mapping are:

- **Generalisation**: The objects to display should be simplified/aggregated in order to adapt their level of detail to the visualisation scale/zoom. In theory, there should be on data layer for each zoom level. The best is to use a multi-scale database. See [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440/) for an overview of existing generalisation techniques.
- **Spatial index service** and **vector tilling**: Only data in the view should be transferred and displayed. To make it possible, a spatial index service (if the objects are small and compact) or pre-computed vector tiles (if the objects are big) could be used.

The best is to use all three techniques as explained in [this excellent document](http://www.ahahah.eu/data/doc/gisscience2012_gaffuri_draft.pdf) !