# GIS storage format for better performance - Android device

Tags: shapefile, kml, android, json, data

We have developed an android application which loads different eco-zones and does geo-fencing based on current GPS location.

We have converted a shapefile to KML, then to JSON format, for loading in the Android app.

The zones had 1000+ vertexes, so performance was an issue. I then tried splitting the polygons, this deforms zone boundaries.

Is there a better approach to this, while respecting zone boundaries, in which the performance could be improved? I.e. less vertices using some other algorithm? or a better GIS data format ?

Comment: You can generalise (simplification) the polygons lightly or aggressively - see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440/what-are-the-existing-solutions-to-automate-generalisation-simplification-of-geo

Comment: If the shapefile was loaded into a spatial database (ie postgis) you can request both json (geojson) and simplified polygons on the fly http://postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Simplify.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your exact workflow, so I'll try to give a general answer.

There are two different ways that geodata can be used, and the answer depends on which one you need:

1. You are showing the data on a map. In this case, if you load 1000+ vertices as graphics on the map, you will have a low performance. What you need to do is to load the data as a raster, say a WMS service or something similar. Delegate the drawing of the layer to something else. How to implement this, depends on you map View. I am not too sure of Google Map API, But you could look into using the [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) library.
2. Your app has the data, but it is used only for querying. Say for example, finding out if the current location is within a zone or not. This can be done by storing the data in a spatial database. We have had a lot of success with [spatilite for Android](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=spatialite-android-tutorial)

You could also go for a hybrid aproach if you need both.